# Graph Database integration with Solr

Tags: solr, neo4j, integration, graph-databases

Are there any graph databases in production that are integrated with Solr?
For example, I know Neo4j has Lucene integration but I'm not sure if you can build Solr on top of it yet.
I believe AWS Neptune will but currently it is not in production so no definite answer.

Any information would help!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, Titan supports Solr as indexing backend:

http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/solr.html

I am confident that you could send your queries directly against solr too, if that is what you are looking for.